# Python algorithm to obtain a randomized negative dataset from a positive dataset

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I have a file containing unique pairs of proteins, the positive dataset. Let's call it `infile`.
Below there's an example of the infile content:

```
Q9VRA8  A1ZBB4
Q03043  Q9VX24
B6VQA0  Q7KML2
```

The entries are tab separated.
The randomized dataset, let's call it `outfile`, must contain combinations of the individual proteins, in a way that they cannot match the content of the infile **in any order**. As an example, for the **first line** above, the randomized outfile cannot contain the following pairs:

```
Q9VRA8  A1ZBB4
A1ZBB4  Q9VRA8
```

Also, the generated negative dataset must contain the exact same number of protein pairs in the positive dataset.
In order to adress this I tried the following:

```
# Read original file
data = list(infile.readlines())
ltotal = len(data)
lwritten = 0

# Split original file in words
with open (infilename, 'rt') as infile:
    pairs = set(frozenset(line.split()) for line in infile)
words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(pairs))
random.shuffle(words)

# Obtain pairs of words
with open(outfilename, 'wt') as outfile:
    for pair in itertools.izip(*[iter(words)] * 2):
        if frozenset(pair) not in pairs and lwritten != ltotal:
            outfile.write("%s\t%s\n" % pair)
            lwritten += 1
```

This works. However, the infile has a total of 856471 lines and the outfile obtains different ranges  of proteins pairs, with a minimum of 713000.

How can I work around this so the number of pairs generated is the exact same as the infile?
Also, I couldn't adress the reverse pair order issue. Any thoughts in both questions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you repeat values?  does the total number of each protein have to match in each file?

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that point. Yes, I can have repeated individual entries. However I cannot have duplicated pairs. All combinations must be unique. And no, the total number of proteins does not have to match each file. Although there should be some balance, or when I use SVM that can create some bias.

Comment: I'm get the impression that you are generating a "background" (sort of null-hypothesis) distribution for the SVM.  Why are you vetoing pairs that already occurred in this artificial data set?

Comment: In SVM you need both positive and negative datasets for training the algorithm. If you only use a positive dataset the algorithm will be overtrained and biased when you use it in the test data.

Comment: Constructing the negative data set without vetoing has a clear statistical interpretation -- the product of any pair is just the product of the probabilities of the items.  I'm curious to know what modelling assumptions lead you to want to drop negative instances that happen to overlap with your observed ones.

Comment: That is an important question. Do you have any paper explaining that? Because after reading articles like this (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1838603/?tool=pubmed) I always got the idea that the negative dataset should absolutely negative, that is, containing not even 1 single entry from the positive one. But it is true, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To veto pairs independent of order, I'd just put both order into my list of pairs:
i.e. I'd add: `line.split()` and `line.split()[::-1]` to the set of pairs.

To generate more pairs, instead of iterating through the list of words, just pick random pairs (using `random.choice` maybe?) and then vetoing them based on the list of invalid pairs (you may also need to consider the case where you generate the pair "A1ZBB4 A1ZBB4" and act appropriately).  You can just keep doing this as long as you like.  Since you need to ensure that the output contains only unique elements, the output items can be added to the veto list (or maintained as a separate veto list) as they are generated.

If you want to reduce the memory footprint you could set up:

- `pairs` is the set of pairs to veto, but each pair is internally sorted, i.e. if you read "Q9VRA8  A1ZBB4" you store it as the pair "A1ZBB4, Q9VRA8".
- you generate random pairs above, check to see if the sorted version of that pair is in your veto list, if so ignore it.

Comment: Oh, I like that vetoing idea. Thanks, that was really useful!